# Listening to all packets on a specific port

Tags: port-forwarding, forwarding, arp, netcat, ports

I'm using `netcat -l 555` option to communicate between two computers on port 555, is there any way I can eavesdrop to whats going on in that conversation from a 3rd computer connected to the same WLAN by listening to the port somehow?  (Im arpspoofing and every packet is transfered through my machine first)

Using Kali linux.

Comment: Presumably you could run `tcpdump` or the like

Comment: @EricRenouf  tcpdump is not showing any closed ports so eavesdropping cant be done.

Comment: I'm not sure what closed ports have to do with `tcpdump`, it doesn't need to open any ports to see what packets are out there, similarly, wireshark should be able to find things going over the air nearby so Mark's suggestion could well solve your problem

Comment: @EricRenouf thanks for the comment, actually in WLAN wireshark only captures packets(in the entire network) in LLC protocol which, you can say, is "raw formation", and im looking for the TCP formation which has the data on its payload without any encryption whatso-ever.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark is a great tool for packet debugging. 
You can set up a display or capture filter and listen for that port.

```
tcp.port == 555
```

Also a nice link on the wireshark wiki on capture filters.
https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Comment: maybe I should have mentioned that im eavesdropping from a 3rd computer and the entire communication is wireless on the same WLAN

Comment: So why can't you run wireshark on that third computer?

Comment: If you are unable to, it might be due to network driver not supporting promiscuous mode, but I never encountered such adapter/driver.

Comment: @Krazor because wireshark only show the packets payload if it is sent to you, if you are sniffing every packet in the WLAN then it captures it in "LLC protocol formation" which is a sub-layer above the first layer and below the second layer and in charge of communication and transfering information , hence Im looking for a tool to eavesdrop the specific port on the specific host, that way I will get the TCP protocol with the right information and not the LLC protocol one which is more general.

Comment: @loa_in_ it does support promiscuous and monitor mode.

Comment: If you're already arp spoofing/poisoning the packets that are being sent from computer_A to Computer_B are already being intercepted. This is called an MiM (man in the middle) attack You're using ettercap right?

Comment: Poison The connection between Computer_A to Computer_B and then use wireshark to capture the traffic.

Comment: @eyal oh, I must have misunderstood your question. You could simply write a little program which will listen on Port 555 on your PC, log to stout and then forward it to the other machine.

Comment: @MarkNicolle Im actually using a simple piece of code which gives me the same results as using ettercap because I prefer the command line-way. And yeah im MITM'ing but this port thing got me stuck since I dont know how to listen to a specific port on the "target" if its a closed port.

Comment: @Krazor you mean running a piece of code on the "target" which will forward all packets at the port to my "attacking" machine? for that I need physical access to the "target" which I do have.. but i want to do it all remotely, thats why im asking for any tool that can do that or an idea/the right code. Im trying to do it all from the "Attcker" without the "target" to know .. just a small project of mine to learn the basics of MITM.